# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(android.Content.Context, int, java.util.ArrayList<MyObject>)

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I know this question has been asked a million times before, but I have tried all of the solutions I can find, and still doesn't work. I have tried calling "this" for context, I have tried getActivity, I have tried getContext(), but nothing seems to work for this fragment in particular. The same code does work in a different fragment tho, which is why I am really confused. Any help appreciated.

My LoginFragment, my issue can be found in setReservations():

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    LoginButton loginButton;
    TextView nameText;
    ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Reservation> reservations;
    ListView lv;
    Profile fbProfile;

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(getContext(), null, null, 1);
        context = getActivity();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.users_name);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        setmProfileTracker();
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        fbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (fbProfile != null)
        {
            updateUI();
        }
        getActivity().setTitle("My page");
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

    private void setmProfileTracker()
    {
        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                updateUI(); //this is the third piece of code I will discuss below
            }
        };
    }

    private void updateUI() {

        boolean enableButtons = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
        if (fbProfile == null) {
            fbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Log.e("Profile", "null");
        }
        if (enableButtons && fbProfile != null) {
            Log.e("Access Token", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().toString());
            nameText.setText(fbProfile.getName());
        }
    }

    private void setReservations()
    {
        reservations = dbHandler.userReservationToArrayList(parseLong(fbProfile.getId()));

        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.reservations);

        ArrayAdapter<Review> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Review>(
            context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            reservations);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should learn more about generics and type safety.

Your `reservations` has type `ArrayList<Reservation>` but you try to create `ArrayAdapter<Review>` which is wrong. Change it to `ArrayAdapter<Reservation>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your Array Adapter is of Type Review

```
ArrayAdapter<Review> arrayAdapter
```

But Your passing :

```
 ArrayList<Reservation> reservations
Change it to ArrayAdapter<Reservation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array of `Review` not an array of `Reservation`. So change your adapter to `ArrayAdapter<Reservation>`.

Also, at the moment you call the `getActivity()` method inside the `onCreateView()` method your `Activity` is not created yet, which can cause an error. 
To solve this issue, you should to move this line to your `onActivityCreated()` :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
    }
```