# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter (Context, int, java.util.List)

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

So I'm trying to read in a `CSV` file and show it in a `ListView`. I've got the csv file in the raw directory and I have successfully read each line and have it outputting to the log. The next step is to take that data and show it in a `ListView`. My data is stored in an `ArrayList`, so I'm trying to use an `ArrayAdapater` but I am presented with the error seen in the question title.

**MainActvity.java:**

```
    private final List<Sample> coordArray = new ArrayList<>();

private void readGPSData() {
    // Read the raw csv file
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rawgps);
    // Reads text from character-input stream, buffering characters for efficient reading
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    );
    // Initialization
    String line = "";
    // Initialization
    try {
        // Step over headers
        reader.readLine();
        // If buffer is not empty
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("MyActivity","Line: " + line);
            // use comma as separator columns of CSV
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            // Read the data
            Sample sample = new Sample();
            // Setters
            sample.setLat(tokens[0]);
            sample.setLon(tokens[1]);

            // Adding object to a class
            coordArray.add(sample);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coordArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Log the object
            Log.d("My Activity", "Just created: " + sample);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Logs error with priority level
        Log.wtf("MyActivity", "Error reading data file on line" + line, e);

        // Prints throwable details
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've used an `ArrayAdapter` plenty of times and have never ran into this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's maybe because of `List<Sample>`? and same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178825/4409113

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that:

```
private final List<Sample> coordArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Is type `Sample` and `ArrayAdapter` is type "String".

`ArrayAdapter` expect same type as `List` have it, which you put then in constructor, solution for you is having same type for example like this:

```
List<Sample> coordArray = new ArrayList<Sample>();
ArrayAdapter<Sample> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coordArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext(`).

Comment: I don't think this would cause issue or an error like: Cannot resolve **constructor**

Comment: @nordine Before you answer the question, maybe consider to test code. Just my 50cent advice to you.